# SOFR transition impact on numerical efficiency

Tags: sofr

As the SOFR transition kick in, the libor insturments and derivatives link to SOFR which poses natural challenge for numerical methods such as lattice, monte carlo and finite difference, where people used to (at least some people) discretize the time steps to be month basis if the security expired in years.

As the nature of SOFR of daily compounding and daily reset, this discretization scheme would likely pose higher mispricing error. If reducing the discretization scheme, it may pose much longer evaluation time.

What people think of this? Any alternate way of handling this?

Comment: This is indeed a very interesting question. I can only offer limited insight into vanilla systems (FO, risk). So this is a Not-so-related comment. From what I see, there are many legacy Systems out there that have poor performance when it comes to pricing (a lot of). „Shortcuts“ for these systems involve calculating forwards at lower frequencies (weekly, monthly etc). For modern pricers I honestly see no bigger problem as they are mostly already highly vectorized and/or store curve calculation results directly in memory (which is really convenient...)

Comment: Thanks @Kermittfrog. You are absolutely right. However, if you looked at numerical procedure such as tree method, finite difference method or Monte Carlo, the likelihood of adding smaller discretization time step would increase run time a lot, espeically if we talk about relative performance measure. 10ms and 5ms both are fast but it double the run time.